# Importing and exporting to a text file - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, diagnostics

I am trying to create a progam which diagnoses your computer by asking you questions. At the moment, the questions and answers are in lists in the program. How would I have all the questions and answers in a .txt file and import them in when the program runs. Also, how would I be able to export the users inputs to another .txt file.
Thanks

Comment: Precisely which part of this are you stuck on? This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; please learn [ask] and provide a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you format your text files as one question or answer per line, you can simple use the `readlines` method of file objects.

Let's say this is the file `foo.txt`:

```
This is the first line.
And here is the second.
Last is the third line.
```

To read this into a list:

```
In [2]: with open('foo.txt') as data:
   ...:     lines = data.readlines()
   ...:     

In [3]: lines
Out[3]: 
['This is the first line.\n',
 'And here is the second.\n',
 'Last is the third line.\n']
```

Note how these lines still contain the newline, which is probably not what you want.
To change that we could do it like this:

```
In [5]: with open('foo.txt') as data:
    lines = data.read().splitlines()
   ...:

In [6]: lines
Out[6]: 
['This is the first line.',
 'And here is the second.',
 'Last is the third line.']
```